# Creating a Visual Representation of an Image Using Base64 Data

Tags: image, image-processing, base64, ascii-art, data-representation

I converted the icon "DH" to base64 string.
By aligning it in a specific way, I can achieve a visual representation that clearly depicts "DH" within the base64 code. Could it not be purely coincidental, could it?

[image: dh]

[image: B64 code]

However, I attempted the same process with the Wikipedia.org icon, a simple black "W" on a white background, but regardless of how I align the base64 code, I am unable to achieve a recognizable "W" visualization.

Is there a specific technique or method to construct an image that, when encoded, can yield such visually recognizable result?